# How to get from replication argument to risk neutral probability

Tags: option-pricing

In the option pricing course, i am introduced the concept of replicating portfolio of an option and the option price must be equal to the cost of the portfolio.

And then, base on this argument, the professor says it is equivalent to the risk neutral probability where every asset would get the risk free rate.

Could you please tell me how to go from the replicating argument to the construction of the risk neutral probability ?

I'm struggling. Thank you very much.

Comment: The intuition is relatively simple. Under the specified assumptions the option can be replicated **without taking any risk**. Therefore if a valuation formula exists this formula cannot depend on the risk-aversion of the investors. The formula must give the same result **for any risk aversion coefficient**, for convenience we can assume  only risk-neutral investors and this must give the same result as the Black-Scholes formula. Of course **it is not true** in reality that all investors are risk neutral. But an economic equilibrium analysis with this assumption will give the correct result.

Comment: @noob2 : Hello, thanks for your answer. Can you please explain what it means by "without taking any risk" ? because I do see the risk of decreasing/increasing in price of stock.